# What does an SD Card do internally during the 74 clock cycles at startup

Tags: digital-communications, sd, firmware

It is documented that the SD Bus Interface requires 74 clock cycles before the first command is sent:

[image]

*Taken from SD Specifications Part 1 Physical Layer, Simplified Specification, Version 6.00*
https://academy.cba.mit.edu/classes/networking_communications/SD/SD.pdf

This leads me to have several related questions which do not appear to be documented in the standard:

1. What does the SD card use these clock cycles for internally?
2. Are the actions the SD card takes internally consistent every time, or do they vary based on the SD card contents or previous commands received?
3. Are the actions the SD card takes consistent between manufacturers or SD card types? I.e. are the internal actions of the SD card dictated by a standard, or are manufacturers free to use these clock cycles as they see fit.

Comment: I suggest you to stress the "up to 74 cycles" part. Disclaimer: I do not know why "74" and not 73 or 1024.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What does the SD card use these clock cycles for internally?

An SD card is nothing less than a microcontroller with a large flash memory attached, among other memories and peripherals (voltage supply control, oscillators, ECC accelerators).

So, as any other microcontroller, it needs to *boot*, i.e., let the oscillator stabilize sufficiently for operation, let internal voltages become nominal, zero out registers, jump to the beginning of its firmware, read device configuration, initialize communication with the flash memory and set up its transceivers.

Just as booting your PC, that simply takes time! Up to one millisecond, in this case.

I suspect it might actually take longer in practice, but that 1 ms is not when the card needs to be able to immediately respond with data to requests (it can make the host wait, anyways, in response to such a request), it needs to be able to react to commands at all.

> Are the actions the SD card takes internally consistent every time, or do they vary based on the SD card contents or previous commands received?

They probably aren't. There's physical randomness and variations in how fast oscillators become ready, and the charge pumps internal to the flash memory will also take time; if there's any configuration to be read from the flash itself, that timing is uncertain.

> Are the actions the SD card takes consistent between manufacturers or SD card types? I.e. are the internal actions of the SD card dictated by a standard, or are manufacturers free to use these clock cycles as they see fit.

I'm not an SD card controller manufacturer, and what exactly their SD card controller chips do internally would belong in the domain of their commercial secrets, but you can be certain that no two generations of cards from the same vendor run the same firmware initialization, and that different vendors use different firmware.

Note that the manufacturer printed on your SD card has very little to do with in whose factory they were built, or who manufactured the actual NAND flash, or which controller they bought, or who wrote the firmware for that controller. Two identically-labeled SD cards from the same vendor can be totally different internally. And that is not even factoring in the fact that [counterfeit brand-name SD cards seem to be very common](https://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?page_id=1022) (same author's very educative [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruEn7TE4YMM) on the topic of exploring how SD cards work).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I totally get that there would be a period of time equivalent to a POR required, but I am less sure why that would need 74 clock cycles, rather than just enforcing a delay before commands as part of a timing diagram in the standard. This, to me, suggests that the 74 clock cycles are being used for something?

Comment: yes, as said, booting; probably specifically one of the prototypes of an early SD card. Don't forget that this is an industry standard, so the people setting the standard actually work for the manufacturers of these chips, and will say something like "well out chip needs 74 cycles, that should be enough for anybody!" because their competitor's chip needs 76 cycles, or so.

Comment: (but probably it just turns out that 1ms is a nice round number, and that happens to be 74 cycles worth of time, and the info that you can count cycles until you reach 74 is just meant to be helpful.)

Comment: incidentally you can talk to sd cards as slowly as you wish.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there's no minimum SD clock frequency and you're even allowed to gate the clock at nearly any time. If the init delay was defined just as "1 ms" instead of `max(1 ms, 74 cycles)`, cards would have to be able to cope with ridiculous situations like the entirety of 1 ms expiring in less than one clock cycle. That would certainly make things much more complicated for the card, and what for?

Answer (score 7):

> I am less sure why that would need 74 clock cycles

It is about the delay being given with the clock cycle period as a unit of time. Since the clock cycle period is already there, it is convenient to use it as a measure of time, as you will soon see.

> rather than just enforcing a delay before commands as part of a timing diagram in the standard

You'd be surprised at how much of a complication this may be to some implementers. If you already have a clock source, it's rather easy to specify delays relative to that clock source. When you specify a delay in absolute terms, without mentioning the clock, many people miss the simple implementation opportunity and think they need separate timers and so on.

This specification suggests a simple implementation technique. Engineers with less experience can take that as a hint and use it. More experienced folks will interpret it in more general terms.

Comment: in fact, it's practically impossible to measure "wall-clock" time instantly if your device doesn't have its own source of power to keep an oscillator running. An oscillator able to be used to measure the duration "1 ms" would need some time to start up itself, and there's nondeterminism in that, so that's not an option. So, one would need some analog way with a massively annoying and imprecise method like having a reference voltage internally, after crossing of which you start charging a reference capacitor with a reference current and then wait until its voltage crosses another reference …

Comment: … voltage; add temperature variations to all this, and you wish that you could just use a simple 7-bit feedback shift register and a bunch of logic gates to wait 74 clock cycles. +1 !

Comment: i found you have to clock it. Waiting for timer does not work.

Answer (score 5):

1. The card can do anything it wants. Maybe nothing, or, maybe it waits for the clocks to deliberately ignore them so that it does not accidentaly determine invalid transitions and glitches on the bus as valid clocked data. Maybe the designers wanted to make sure that to start the card in native mode or SPI mode, the CS signal is activated or deactivated by host before sending the reset command CMD0. Bear in mind that the SD cards also are based on MMC cards which were introduced two years earlier in 1997. The cards and their ASIC or MCU might have been very different back then, requiring some clock pulses for resetting them, than current cards. But by specification and downward compatibility, you still need to initialize the cards like were initialized 25 years ago.
2. No, definitely not consistent. While the card look like linear sequence of data blocks like any mass media, the Flash storage is handled by complex wear leveling algorithms. You never know how much it takes for a write to complete, because the card can have an empty flash sector available for writing, or, it may need to erase a larger group of sectors first before it can write the data. Which means there are inconsistent delays and current/energy consumption per write of each sector.
3. The 74 initial clock cycles is worded "up to 74". It may not require a single clock pulse before being ready to receive CMD0. But each manufacturer, each card, each card that are identical but already used differently, will take different amount of clock cycles to respond when they are ready with any operation, and that is OK as long as the host device and the card are expecting the clock cycles or time to be within the minimum and maximum ratings allowed in the specification. For example different hosts may use the card at different clock speed so there will be different amount of clocl cycles, even if it takes the card exactly same amount of wall clock time to signal when it is ready.